# Two method in my implementation of a linkedList, find number of occur and position of element tested results

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, linked-list

Here is the method:

```
public int occurrences(D elem) {

        if (elem == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        int occur = 0;
        Node curr = head;

        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.data == elem) {
                occur++;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return occur;
    }
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test
    public void testNumOccur() {
        ListInOrder<Integer> list = new ListInOrder<>();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(8);
        assertEquals(2, list.numOccurrencesOfElement(5));
    }
```

And the results when I run:
expected <2> but was <3>

My other method is acting odd when tested:

```
public int posOfElem(D elem) {

    if (elem == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int ind = 0;
    Node curr = head.next;
    while (curr != null) {
        if (elem.equals(curr.data)) {
            return ind;
        }
        ind++;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

My test:

```
@Test
public void posOfElemTest() {
    ListInOrder<Character> list = new ListInOrder<>();
    list.add('c');
    list.add('b');
    list.add('v');
    list.add('g');
    list.add('y');
    list.add('r');

    assertEquals(2, list.positionOfElement('v'));

}
```

when tested the results output:
expected <2> but was <4>

Could really use help on this.
Thank you

Comment: You will need to include the other code you wrote. Insertion at least

Comment: For finding the position, there is an util list.indexOf('v').. For finding the occurences, Collections.frequency(list, 5). We dont need to write the logic, When the Utils are already provided by.

Comment: @saranyadeviM cannot use that. Am limited to making my own from scratch.

Comment: @yre Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - In addition to the comment of  nhouser9: from what you posted you're not even call the methods shown from your tests. Please change your example to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)